# Grpc C++ DNS overrides

Tags: grpc-c++

I am trying to connect a grpc-c++ client to a grpc-c++ server. I already have a grpc-java client connected with working TLS so the server should be functioning correctly.

However inside grpc-java there is a method when building a channel named 'overrideAuthority'. From the documentation the method

> "Overrides the authority used with TLS and HTTP virtual hosting. It does not change what host is actually connected to. Is commonly in the form host:port."

I was attempting to find something similar for the c++ client. However, so far all I have found is a function named set_authority() on the grpc::ClientContext as well as two options used with grpc_channel_args which are GRPC_ARG_DEFAULT_AUTHORITY and GRPC_SSL_TARGET_NAME_OVERRIDE_ARG.

None of these seem to have any effect on the authority at all. The server will always reject the connection with the error

> No match found for server name: 0.0.0.0.

P.S. I am aware that I can add it to the common name on the certificate (and I will if I need to). However, if possible I would like to follow the same pattern as the grpc-java client.

Answer (score 0):

`GRPC_SSL_TARGET_NAME_OVERRIDE_ARG` is the right channel arg. Please take a look at some of the tests https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/470a3066c74abc7c2a0a2cab3b35000b27b51af1/test/core/end2end/fixtures/h2_ssl.cc#L133
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/470a3066c74abc7c2a0a2cab3b35000b27b51af1/test/cpp/end2end/xds/xds_end2end_test.cc#L1348

Additionally, if I remember correctly, this log just serves as a warning and does not result in disconnections. Please collect some more verbose logs https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md. That might give more hints as to what's going on here.